# routing asp.net webforms physical file are not been ignore

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes

I am trying to use asp routing in webforms.

want to route home page to defaut.aspx

all other aspx pages to cms.aspx

I made this line of code in global

```
      routes.MapPageRoute(//this for home page
       "Home",
       string.Empty,
       "~/Default.aspx"
   );
    routes.MapPageRoute("defaultRoute", "{*value}", "~/cms.aspx");//all other pages
```

this works in localhost

```
http://localhost:36443 //redirect to default.aspx 

http://localhost:36443/page1//redirect to cms.aspx
```

The problem start here:

```
http://localhost:36443/page1/somevalue
```

This time the routing doesn't recognize the physical file(css js... etc) and start routing them to cms.aspx.

in the production website:

```
http://mySubDomain.website.com
```

the problem is even more weird ,wcf are routing to cms.aspx.

for example this link:

```
http://subdomain.website.com/WebServices/webservice.svc/webserviceFunction
```

redirect to cms.aspx instead of ignore the physical file svn.

I tried all kind of ignore with no effect at all

```
 routes.Ignore("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}");
 routes.Ignore(("{file}.svn"));
 routes.Ignore("{*allcss}", new { allcss = @".*\.css(/.*)?" });
 routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", new { alljpg = @".*\.jpg(/.*)?" });
 routes.Ignore("{*svc}", new { alljs = @".*\.svc(/.*)?" });
```

I think microsoft toke a routing from mvc to webform without single tought about it.

Does anyone know how to go around this problem.

Thanks

Baaroz

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/path to script ")%>'></script>
```

or

```
 routes.Ignore("{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}");
```

but you need to write ("the name of folder that you palce js file /{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}");
to can use it